# Check if string matches a specific pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i look into text recognition of licensplates. Im using google cloude service for this.

it returns me a list of possible stuff. But also text on the image not containing the license plates get recognized. So i thought i could just tell python to take from the list the one text that matches the pattern of the license plate.

For germany it is like this:

1 or 3 letters. 1 Whitespace.1 or 2 letters. whitespace. up to 4 numbers.

So i have basically 3 parts. In the smalles case it could be something like

H A 4

In the biggest case something like

HHH AB 1234

Hope it got clear. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You say '1 or 3 letters' but your example has 2...

Comment: I overlooked that. Thanks I fixed it. 1 to 3 letters is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex for this:

```
^[A-Z]{1,3}\s[A-Z]{1,2}\s\d{1,4}$
```

An explanation:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{1,2}               any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (between 1
                           and 2 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{1,2}               any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (between 1
                           and 2 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about regex. Is it case sensitive?

Comment: Yes - if you want case-insensitive you probably want to replace `[A-Z]` with `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
import re
string='frg3453453HHH AB 1234e456 2sf 3245 yKDEH A 4 554YFDN'
print(re.findall('[A-Z]{1,3}\s[A-Z]{1,2}\s\d{1,4}',string))
```

Output:

```
['HHH AB 1234', 'DEH A 4']
```

Comment: This is a good rough pattern.  But beware of `\w` as it means *word* in the *Python identifier* sense, not in the *natural language* sense.  Throw some underscore ('_') characters in your string, or longer digit strings, and you'll see your pattern begin to fail.  Once you have it working like you do, tighten up the `\w{...}` patterns to mean *exactly* what you want.